# Plot panda df with two variables

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I have the following dataframes `dfS1` and `dfS2`:

```
dfS1
                 var1      var2       var3
Intensity0 -19.318328 -3.074213  -9.178206
Intensity1 -18.784095 -3.757662 -10.017049
Intensity2 -17.720688 -4.144756 -10.912899

dfS2
                var1      var2      var3
Amplitude0 -0.146261  0.017926  0.412654
Amplitude1 -0.853830  0.081825  0.402913
Amplitude2 -0.476011  0.067459  0.265233
```

I manage to plot them idependently by using a simple `dfS1.plot()`

[image]

and `dfS2.plot()`

[image]

My objective is to arrange the two `df` in such way that the two pltos are combined and if possible, plot the lines of one of the `df` with a different style (I am thinking about dash-line but the same colorus as `var1`, `var2` and `var3` are common).

Answer (score 1):

You should explicitly specify axes. It can be achieved using `plt.subplots`. For dashed lines you simply need to add parameter `style="--"`, and to reset color sequence use `plt.gca().set_prop_cycle(None)`. To specify limits on Y axis use `plt.ylim(low, high)`.

The code is as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
dfS1.plot(style="--", ax=ax)

plt.gca().set_prop_cycle(None)
dfS2.plot(ax=ax)

plt.ylim(-1, 1)
```

Comment: I see thanks for the tip. Is there any way to break to `Y axis` to specific values to have a better visualization of the data range? `dfS2` has values between -1 + 1 and with the new plot, the variation is not very visible + A little sub question, would it be possible to specify somehow that the new plot should be only for `var1` for example?

Comment: @GCGM added how to specify y range in answer. To plot only `var1`, you need to select it, e.g. `dfS1["var1"].plot()`